# Выбор цены в зависимости от значения

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который меняет. Переключает цену, но не работает почему то с только целыми числами. Как переделать его?

```
    <div class="selected">
          <select>
            <option value="100" selected>м3</option>
            <option value="100,30">шт</option>
          </select>
</div>
<div class="short-price fx-1 nowrap value"></div>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    let rub = ' руб.'
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.selected'), function(e) {
        // Получаем значение по-умолчанию
        let select = e.querySelector('select'); // Берём в переменную select
        if(select && select.value != 0) { // Если он существует и его значение (по сути значение выбранного в нём option (именно value)) не равен 0 (это если у выбранного option value пустой или отсутствует)
          var v = select.parentNode.querySelector('.value'); // Тут так же как и в функции n(), берём .value который лежит выше
          v.style.display = 'inline-block'; // Ставим ему `inline-block`
          v.innerText = select.value+rub // и пишем значение select
        }
        // ------
        e.addEventListener("change", n)
      })
```

Comment: Предположу, что 100,30 = строка, попробуйте 100.30
Либо приведите значение к типу число с плавающей точкой

Comment: а скрипт не переделать?

Comment: select.value приведите к числу
https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion
Сейчас у вас тип string похоже)

Comment: А можете помочь?

Comment: У вас `</div>` не хватает в конце HTML кода.

Comment: А что за функция такая `n()`? В коде её нет.

Comment: мне тут писали этот скрипт, а так див не хватает. Буду признателен если поможете